Custom build PC hangs sometimes without any logs
My custom built PC hangs sometimes (intermittently) without any logs. Unfortunately, when it freezes, the keyboard and mouse become unresponsive, requiring a forceful power off. Here is the configuration:



Name
Description




CPU
Intel Core i9-13900K


GPU
MSI GeForce RTX 3090 VENTUS 3X 24G


RAM
Corsair DDR5-5600MHz 64GB (2 x 32GB)


SSD
CORSAIR MP600 PRO Low Profile Series 500 GB


HDD
Seagate BarraCuda 7200rpm 3.5" 2TB


Motherboard
ASUS PRIME Z790-P-CSM


SMPS
Corsair RM1000x Power Supply 1000W


Cooling
Cooler Master MasterLiquid ML240L V2 ARGB


Monitor
LG 27UL500-W Monitor Display, 27 inches, 4K



It is a dual-boot PC (Windows 10 + Ubuntu 22.04). This situation happens in both OS. The dmesg did not show something concrete on Ubuntu OS after restarting the PC. Note that I couldn't see dmesg precisely at that time because the PC was not responding. What are the ways to debug such problem?

This situation happens in both OS means hardware issue. Start by the usual: Update UEFI and SSD's firmware, if applicable. Also regarding the choice of OSes: Windows 10 is old and with less than one year of support left therefore a bad choice; Ubuntu 22.04 is now 2 years old, therefore quite older than your hardware. In a nutshell both are BAD choices.

@ChanganAuto: Thank you so much. "... means hardware issue", I guessed the same. "Update UEFI firmware" Do you mean ASUS BIOS update? If so, I can do it. "... quite older than your hardware", I will upgrade to Windows 11 and Ubuntu 24.04 soon. Thank you again.

@ChanganAuto BIOS and SSD firmware are updated. OS are upgraded to Windows 11, and Ubuntu 24.04. So far PC did not hang. Thank you very much.

@ChanganAuto It does hang a while agp. Where should I look up to find the root cause? syslog?
